# Return to original view from MVC action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, exceptionfilterattribute

Im working on a asp.net core website and im trying to make som global validation exception handling using Filters. The backend can at random places throw fluentapi ValidationException and I want to catch these and show the error messages to the user. This filter only cares about ValidationExceptions. All other exceptions will be handled later..

Instead of using a try/catch in every post action in all my controllers, I want to use a filter that catches only ValidationExceptions, add the errors to the ModelState and then return to the original view with the updated ModelState.

I have tried many things but every time I just get a blank page after the filter finishes. I can easily set a new RedirectToRouteResult witht the controller and action from the context. But then I dont have the ModelState and values the user entered..

```
public class PostExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is FluentValidation.ValidationException)
        {
            var ex = context.Exception as FluentValidation.ValidationException;
            context.Exception = null;
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            foreach (var item in ex.Errors.ToList())
            {
                context.ModelState.AddModelError(item.PropertyName, item.ErrorMessage);
            }

            // Done with the stuff I want.
            // Now please go back to the original view with the updated modelstate and values
        }
        else if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // Do something else...
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else...
        }
        base.OnException(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen [this](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2018/10/29/customizing-aspnetcore-09-actionfilters.html)?

Comment: My problem is not about using filters as such.. it's how to redirect to the original view with the same model and modelstate. But since im in a filter I can't just do like return View(model) as I would in the controller action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the particlar `Model`(related to Action Method) in `Exception Filters`. So you have to handle the error at `Controller` level if you want to add `Errors` to model.

```
try
{
    //Do something
}
Catch(Exception e)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string key, string errorMessage);
    Return View(model)
}
```

The error message will present itself in the `<%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>` in your `View`

Without `try-catch` blocks you won't know if `exception` occured in Action Method, So that you can add Custom Errors to Model.